# 1980s horror program where a birdwatcher is found ripped to pieces on a fog covered island

Tags: story-identification, tv

This a long shot. Back in the early 80s (when I was about the 10 years old,) my parents let me watch a couple of minutes of a horror program on RTE. I think the program was a British production.

In the program, the locals live on a fog covered island. A bird watcher is found, ripped to pieces. Next to the body, they find a tape recorder. Later, when its played in a local pub, the birdwatcher talks about the fog when someone attacks him. In the recording, you can hear the attacker laughing as he kills the birdwatcher. The laughter was unnatural / inhuman. And everyone was shocked as they listened to it.

After that, my parents sent me to bed. Any idea as to the name of the program?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this actually a supernatural killer, or is there some other reason to believe this is on-topic?

Comment: Hi DavidW, good question. The laughter was unnatural / inhuman. And everyone was shocked as they listened to it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've just worked it out. Only forty years after seeing. DavidW's question jogged my memory

*[The Nightmare Man](https://timewarriors.co.uk/2020/12/21/tw-remembers-the-nightmare-man/)*

> It had all the elements of classic scare fests with the isolated island, wild open moors favoured by American Werewolf in London, fog sealing off the island, frightened dogs, animal attacks and murders where the victims were torn apart by some unseen force which leaves behind a radioactive trace. And oh yes, someone saw a flying saucer crashing and that’s when they find bite marks that don’t belong to a human. Every possibility is explored from alien monsters, satanic cults, serial killers, genetic experiments on humans and animals before the monster is revealed. The alien theory is reinforced when a mysterious blood stained craft is found on the beach.
>
> .....
>
> Camfield is an expert at building tension and in the Nightmare Man he achieves it in abundance. Every monster attack is unnerving including the sheep attacks. One avid bird watcher is ripped apart in his tent on the moors while his camera takes pictures and the attack on the coast guard station shows just how effective and terrifying you can make a scene on a limited budget. The click of the Geiger counter is now a portent of doom and the only way the locals have to know something nasty is lurking in the dark. Such is the tension, you’re waiting for the monster to attack every time someone ventures outside into the fog which never lets up. Everything here is meant to terrify the viewers especially the scene where **they manage to develop the bird watcher’s camera and listen to the recording of his death**. We see a humanoid figure with what seems to be things growing out of its head, reinforcing the notion that this is not human, especially since the amount of radiation it generates would leave a human six feet under. The most chilling of all is the inhuman noise it makes when murdering; **it is laughing as it rips its victims to bits**.

I've spent so long wondering about that program :)

Comment: Great!  You can't accept your own answer right away, but please make sure you accept it in a couple of days when that's available.